# C# .net core 2.0, loop is over counting

Tags: c#, for-loop, .net-core

I have a fairly simple for loop, that we've all used thousands of times, but I am getting a weird error.  As I doubt there is a failing in C# .net core, I was looking for help with my error:

```
        public Int2DBoard GetNonMatchingSquaresThisBoardOnly(Int2DBoard other)
    {
        // create a tempBoard:
        Int2DBoard tempBoard = new Int2DBoard("Different");
        // create a match bool to hold our result:
        bool match = false;
        // match this board items against other board
        for (int i = 0; i < board.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < other.board.Count; i++)
            {
                if (other.board[j] == board[i])
                {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!match)
            {
                tempBoard.board.Add(board[i]);
            }
        }
        return tempBoard;
    }
```

When I run this, I get an out of bounds error, checking this I get the following information:

i = 2;
board.Count = 2;

How is this possible?  The function clearly states < board.Count.  I am sure to be missing something obvious, but I just can't see it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the debugger showing the values:

[Overflowing loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXNgz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` instead of `j` in the inner loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < other.board.Count; i++)
```

Change it to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < other.board.Count; j++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `i++` in the inner loop instead of `j++`